# How to calculate time with a php force download script?

Tags: php, .htaccess, time, download

I have a rather simple force download script:

```
$thefile = $_GET['id'];
$file = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/test/'.$thefile;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$thefile); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
@readfile($file);
```

And it works nicely, except it does not show how much time is remaining ("could not calculate time").

I found someone with a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547471/file-size-will-not-display-on-php-download-script-during-file-download), by using this code:

```
# for URL paths that begin with "/foo/bar/"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/foo/bar/ no-gzip=1

# for files that end with ".py"
<FilesMatch \.py$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

But alas, I can not get that to work. My files are media files (avi, wmv, mp4 and so forth), so I assumed I would have to modify the code along these lines:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/test/ no-gzip=1

<FilesMatch "\.(avi|wmv|mp4|mpg|mpeg|m4v)$">
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

I have also changed the path to a simple test folder, but time is still not being displayed.

How to?

Answer (score 0):

You should add content-length header, for your browser to know total file size.

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
```

Take a look at [this example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#86554).

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried that (header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));) but to avail.

Comment: @EmilyAdler Disabling GZIP and returning Content-length should do the trick. If it doesn't- check the headers returned by your server to your browser. For Firefox there is a nice plugin called Tamper Data.